# Displaying tax total and total using purchase price? Python programming

Tags: python

```
print ("What is/was your original purchase price?")
x = input
valx=float(x)

print ("Amount of original purchase: ${}"
   .format(valx))
print ("State sales tax on original purchase: ${}"
   .format(valx*.04))
print ("County sales tax on original purchase: ${}"
   .format(valx*.02))
print ("Total sales tax (county and state): ${}"
   .format(valx*.06))
print ("Total of the sale (original purchase and total sales tax): ${}"
   .format(valx*.06))
```

this makes sense to me and I've used this method in the past, however it doesn't work now.

```
Output error: line 9, in <module>builtins.TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

basically my goal is to display the amount of the original purchase, the amount of the state sales tax(4%) on the original purchase, the amount of the county sales tax(2%) original purchase, the total sales tax (county tax plus state tax), and final the total of the sale (which is the sum of the amount of the original purchase plus the total sales tax).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to retrieve input from the command line would be this:

```
valx=float(input("What is/was your original purchase price?"))
```

`input` is a string, and you convert it to a float by wrapping that call.  You then don't need the extra variable.

Answer (score 3):

You're assigning a *function* to the variable `x`

```
x = input
>> x
<built-in function input>
```

So you're not giving the `float()` function a string or number, but a function.

I think what you're trying to do is *call* the `input()` function. You can also integrate your message into it.

```
x = input ("What is/was your original purchase price?")
```

Or if you're using **python 3** or greater, you'll need to convert the input from *string to float* (or integer, or whatever type you want.):

```
x = float(input("What is/was your original purchase price?"))
```

Comment: ohhh ic...how do I change this to do what I want which is not a function? but along the line of what I'm trying (ie: x*.02 x*.04 etc)?

Comment: @user1693293 - What you have is almost fine, but you need to **call** the `input()` function to get input from the user.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably there are 6 lines above that you thought we didn't need to see. It makes talking about line 9 a bit useless though.

Surely you mean to *call* the input function

```
x = input()
```

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, you should use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`. The latter is the same as `eval(raw_input(prompt))` and eval is not far from evil :)